# Cannot launch eclipse from Unity Launcher

Tags: unity, launcher, icons, eclipse

I recently downloaded the Eclipse package and placed it in a folder in my Home directory, without blending the installation with anything else in the system. Eclipse opens normally, if I use the executable in the installation directory.

The first time I opened the program, the launcher icon appeared in the unity bar, and after I closed it, the launcher icon stayed there, as I have seen happening with other downloaded programs I have just downloaded and executed but not installed on Ubuntu. However, clicking on the launcher after that first time fails to open up Eclipse, with no explanation. The launcher just flashes for a bit, then stops and nothing happens. That is not the case with other such launchers, and as I said the original executable works fine. Any ideas on this?

I have Ubuntu 14.04 and Eclipse J2EE version 4.5.0

EDIT: Content of `eclipse.desktop` located in `home/USERNAME/.local/share/applications/`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Java EE - Eclipse 
Icon=eclipse.png
Path=/home/username/eclipse
Exec=/usr/bin/java -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6 -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xms40m -Xmx512m -jar /home/username/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -showsplash /home/username/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.4.2.v20150204-1700/splash.bmp -launcher /home/username/eclipse/eclipse -name Eclipse --launcher.library /home/username/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20150204-1316/eclipse_1607.so -startup /home/username/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar --launcher.appendVmargs -exitdata 49001d -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -vm /usr/bin/java -vmargs -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6 -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xms40m -Xmx512m -jar /home/username/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
StartupNotify=false
StartupWMClass=Eclipse
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
X-UnityGenerated=true
```

EDIT: The result from executing the commands after `Exec` is this:
`Error: Unable to access jarfile /home/username/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar`, and that's logical, because there is no such file in that folder. The one that exists is `org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar`, and replacing that name in the launcher file made it work.

Comment: Look for a file called `eclipse.desktop` or similar. It could be in `/usr/share/applications/` or `home/YOURUSERNAME/.local/share/applications/`. If you found it, [edit] your question to include the file's content, please.

Comment: What happens if you execute the line after `Exec=` in a terminal?

Comment: Added the result. Why would such an error occur? Also should I post that edit as answer?

Comment: See the duplicate. Occasionally, Eclipse produces an incorrect `.desktop` file . please mention if you still have difficulties, but the linked solution should fix it.